# Storing/Validating against checksum in an embedded system

Tags: c, linker, embedded, checksum

I have an embedded system with flash storage. The program is stored in flash. I have a function that calculates the checksum of the .text section of flash where my non volatile code is stored. I would like to compare the computed checksum with a value fixed and known at compile time stored in flash. I made a new flash section in the linker. I want to fill it with 0xABCD, which is the checksum. How can I do this in the linker? The compiler is GCC

Comment: So, do you actually need the checksum compared at link time? What should happen if they don\`t match?

Comment: controlled system failure. Essentially don't boot throw a message to the user.

Comment: The quick & dirty solution: allocate room for a const variable in another flash segment. Initialize it to any random number. Write the program so that it compares the checksum against this variable. Build the program and run it. Write down the calculated checksum. Go back and modify the variable to the calculate checksum.

Comment: That sounds like you are to add some checks to the boot loader rather than the linker, for the latter has nothing to do with booting the target system.

Comment: The quick & sane solution: get a MCU with on-chip ECC support.

Comment: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/06/23/filling-unused-memory-with-the-gnu-linker/

Comment: *controlled system failure. Essentially don't boot throw a message to the user.* - What system? Which user? The linking is happening on a host computer, not on embedded system.

Comment: You want the linker to make a section to store the checksum to expect in. The other thing you want is that the boot process verifies and causes controlled failure. True?

Comment: What kind of checksum by the way? A pure memory failure checksum? Or cryptographic checksum as part of a tamper-prevention? Simplechecksums like CRC allow to setup flash memory so that the checksum is always 0 (or any other chosen constant). Then verifying it can be hardcoded, without the need to read the checksum to expect from anywhere.

Comment: Memory failure CRC. How do I set up flash to guarantee a CRC value?

Comment: Its an attractive idea, but if the flash memory is NOR flash, I would not bother in most applications.  The chances of error in the code segment after programming are much lower than the chances of an error in your checking implementation.  Moreover if the code you are running to perform the check is stored or executing from the flash memory you are checking is it really going to run?  Use the flash memory's sector write protection features if any to prevent accidental modification instead - especially if you are writing to other parts of the same memory at run-time. Or @Lundin's suggestion.

Comment: I agree. My boss would not. I'm porting code that used to be burned onto PROM. The prom burner would stick the checksum in the last address. He wants that implemented and checked against. The new board has all internal flash which can only be written to with executable code. Hence my question

Comment: In what format is the new code provided to the executable code that does the programming?

Comment: . ELF file gets flashed to the board

Comment: @user1426923 : More likely that your development tool translates the ELF file to binary and programs it.  The ELF file contains metatdata not loaded on the target.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are check-summing is generated by the linker, so getting the linker to generate it directly in one pass is not possible.

A simpler approach perhaps is to simply reserve the checksum storage area in the linker script unprogrammed (0xFFFF) and the add then calculate and add the checksum post-link using a tool such as the [SRecord utilities](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/).  Essentially doing what your PROM burner (mentioned in comment) used to do.

Comment: For stupid IT reasons, installing SREC will be a pain in the ass. Is there a way I could do the following? Set aside section by defining an empty 4 byte section in the linker, do nothing with it. Run my code in debug, calculate the crc live while in debug, and write down the value. Go back to the linker and FILL the empty section with that value?

Comment: Writing your own post processor to patch in the checksum is simple enough, but I'd suggest applying it to the raw binary or hex file rather than the elf file. If the check is performed by a separate bootloader, this is simple, but if the code is self-checking, the check will need to be skipped or ignored in debug.